# Coordinate Data non-conformant

Tags: r, formatting, coordinates, transform

I have have received data in the following long-lat format (3 examples):

```
x<-c(21.568216, 21.550362, 21.549982)
y<-c(100.4606,100.4362,100.4797)
```

I need to transform this data into UTM Zone 47 by using R. I am trying this by using the following post: [the post at the very bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639967/converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm). But I get always the error:

```
Error in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = <S4 object of class "CRS">) : 
  Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: 100.522355
```

I have tried other approaches like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706369/convert-latitude-longitude-to-state-plane-coordinates) or [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142156/r-how-to-get-latitudes-and-longitudes-from-a-rasterlayer) but the problem persists. I have come to the conclusion that the formatting of my data is not in the right format. What is wrong with my data and how can I make it right?

Comment: From `?proj4string`: `attempts to assign an object containing “longlat” to data extending beyond longitude [-180, 360] or lattitude [-90, 90] will be stopped.` My guess is that you are exceeding that limit.

Comment: That means my x and Y coordinates are named wrong? So y is x and x is y?

Comment: Well, is your `x` actually lattitude? If yes, then you mixed them up. If no, then I don't know why your `y` exceeds 90 in this case. Also, I don't know enough about these functions to further comment on it, but this was the first thing I found.

Comment: I think this is one problem solved! Thanks, a few remain.