# Plot a map with mercator projection in R

Tags: r, dictionary, projection, shapefile

I would like to plot a map with a Mercator projection with a file .shp in R.

Here my commands,

```
a=readShapeSpatial("map.shp", CRS("+proj=longlat + +ellps=GRS80"))
map=spTransform(a, CRS=CRS("+proj=merc +ellps=GRS80"))
```

And I have the error message:

```
non finite transformation detected:
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 

  failure in Polygons 8 Polygon 113 points
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
2 projected point(s) not finite
```

i would appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is that shape file?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, probably your coordinates are not correct. Also see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880294/non-finite-transformation-detected-in-sptransform-in-rgdal-r-package) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880294/non-finite-transformation-detected-in-sptransform-in-rgdal-r-package), and [this final link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-November/013443.html) to R-help. I found these by googling for `non finite transformation detected`.